# What type of GPS data is this?

Tags: gps

I have a CCTR-800 Portable GPS tracker and I'm receiving data from it in the following format:

```
*130622214449UB05CW9999C00017093214449A28.452306052.197705130622129.0111111111L000000^
*130622214449UA010214449A28.452306052.197705130622129.0111111111L000000^
```

Someone have an ideia of what format is this?
I know that the first numbers are date/time: 13-06-22 21:44:49.

Comment: Maybe this will help.  http://www.gpstracker7.com/upfile/download/2013012214354945731.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, it's Viczone's protocol:

http://www.gps-profi.ru/tech/Communication_Protocol_for_VIC-T801.pdf

Answer (score 0):

So if you break the line up into segments based on the letters you end up with something like this

```
*130622 214449 UB05 CW9999 C00017093214449 A28.452306052.197705130622129.0111111111 L000000

*130622 214449 UA010214449                 A28.452306052.197705130622129.0111111111 L000000
```

I would start with getting a list of coordinates or where the points were recorded and try correspond the points you recorded with the data.

The first grouping is going to be date and time

The second grouping UB / UA / CW / C seems to change based on the line. Does it always alternate like that? Do the numbers change based on location?

The third grouping A seems repeatable and may be location data

The last grouping L seems kinda of useless but it could change based on other parameters. Does it always report back 0?

Can you move to the GPS to from point to point (say one end of your room to the other) and get repeatable or similar numbers?

It would be worth a shoot to look up if anyone else has worked with that type of GPS.